# Прошедшее время глагола?

Tags: глаголы, времена

Да, знаю, программа пятого класса... Но я не могу все равно разобраться.

В предложении "*Не может быть такого, что бы тебя что-то не устраивало*" в каком времени глагол "*устраивало*"? Вроде бы в прошедшем, однако действие как предшествует моменту речи, так и предполагает, что действие все еще продолжается в настоящем и не исключено в будущем. Извините, не могу это объяснить никак иначе... Уповаю на ваше понимание моей проблемы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не может быть такого, **чтобы** тебя что-то не устраивало.

СПП с придаточным изъяснительным, союз ЧТОБЫ (вместо нейтрального союз ЧТО) выражает ирреальную модальность (возможность, предположительность действия), поэтому глагол стоит в **сослагательном наклонении**.

Сослагательное наклонение использует **форму прошедшего времени**, но значения прошедшего времени **не выражает**. Глаголы в сослагательном наклонении не изменяются по лицам и временам (только по родам и числам).

Другой пример: Не может быть, чтобы он бросил детей.

Comment: Большое спасибо! За "чтобы" отдельное -- оплошал...

Answer (score 1):

> Вроде бы в прошедшем

Нет, это сослагательное наклонение, у него нет категории времени, относиться может к любому из трех грамматических времен.

То, что она совпадает по форме с прошедшим временем - следствие исторической грамматики, в которой форма глагола, отвечающая за современное прошедшее время, была на самом деле особой формой причастия, временных форм не имеет, а частица "бы" - особой формой глагола "быть" - вот она-то и отвечала за грамматическое время. С развитием языка всё упростилось, "бы" превратилось в частицу, а категория время в сослагательном наклонении исчезла вовсе.